# java.io.IOException:java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

Tried one sample of handling a table in hbase from hive.

The CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE command was successful, but the select statement gives a class cast exception

ENV:
hive 0.12.0, hbase 0.96.1, hadoop 2.2  , Ubuntu 12.04 on Virtual box

```
hive> SHOW TABLES;                                                                   
OK
hbatablese_myhive
Time taken: 0.309 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> SELECT * FROM hbatablese_myhive;
OK
```

**Failed with exception

```
java.io.IOException:java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable**
Time taken: 1.179 seconds

hive> 

The same table on HBASE console:

hbase(main):002:0> scan 'myhive'
ROW                                   COLUMN+CELL                                                                                           



 row1                                 column=ratings:userid, timestamp=1392886585074, value=user1                                               
 row2                                 column=ratings:userid, timestamp=1392886606457, value=user2                                               
2 row(s) in 0.0520 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a `Writables.copyWritable(Result result, Result value)` call in an old version of the `next(Immutablebyteswritable key, Result value)` method of TableRecordReaderImpl.java.

the `copyWritable` has been removed now and only works with Writable, Writable arguments.

To do a copy now, you need to use `value.copyFrom(result)`. This will do a deep copy of the data from source to destination

I am guessing you have some library mismatch which is making these calls happen and trying to cast from Result, Result to Writable, Writable